# Data is not loaded into grid from database using servlet and extjs

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, extjs

I have a grid where I want to display the data from the database. Currently my grid displays fine but no data are loaded from the database and I do not get any error either. Any help would be appreciated!

My model **Student.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Student', {
 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

 fields: [
     {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
     {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
     {name: 'address', type: 'string'},
     {name: 'phone', type: 'string'},
     {name: 'email', type: 'string'},
     {name: 'faculty', type: 'string'}
 ]
 });
```

And my **StudentStore**:

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.store.StudentStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'MyApp.model.Student',
sorters: ['name'],
autoLoad: true,
autoSync: false,
proxy: {
    method: 'GET',
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/extServlet/StudentController?action=listStudent',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'StudentStore'
    }
}
});
```

And lastly my **List.js** where the grid is placed

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.List', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
xtype: 'mainlist',
title: 'Student Records',
scrollable: true,
margin: 20,
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},
reference: 'studentGrid',
frame: true,
collapsible: true,
store: 'StudentStore',
collapsible: true,
columns: [
    { 
        text: 'Name', 
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 1 
    },

    { 
        text: 'Address', 
        dataIndex: 'address', 
        flex: 1 
    },
    { 
        text: 'Phone', 
        dataIndex: 'phone', 
        flex: 1
    },
    { 
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    },
    { 
        text: 'Faculty',
        dataIndex:'faculty',
        flex: 1
    }
]
});
```

Note I have loaded **store** and **model** in **Application.js** file.

Here is my servlet code which uses **getStudents()** that returns the **arraylist of the students**.

```
 response.setContentType("application/json");
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(studentdao.getStudents()));
```

Comment: I am using chrome and it does not show any errors

Comment: I am following MVVM structure and its clear the way I have separated Student.js as model, StudentStore.js as store. Can you please show me ur way. I am new to Extjs

Comment: Could we see what kind of structure are you getting after invoking this: `http://localhost:8080/extServlet/StudentController?action=listStudent`

Comment: I am getting nothing on the browser or console. Pawel Glowacz

Comment: I am using ExtJs 6 and theres a place to define views and stores in the application.js. As told I am new at ExtJs.

Comment: If you dont see any json structure after invoking your url you wont get any data in extjs grid. Fix this first.